# not able to override some default image atttributes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a card body and inside the card body, I want a cover pic and top of that, the name and pic of the author of that photo but right now, the author pic is too huge covering almost the whole card body overshadowing the card background image. How do I bring down the author pic to around 30x30px size. right now it's 160x160px.

```
<div key={photo.id} className="grid__item card">
        <div className="card__body">
          <img
            src={photo.urls.small}
            alt=""
            onClick={() => setModalIsOpen(true)}
          />
          <div className="card__footer media">
            <img
              src={photo.user.profile_image.small}
              alt=""
              width="30px"
              className="media__obj"
            />
            <div className="media__body">
              <a href={photo.user.portfolio_url} target="_blank">
                {photo.user.name}
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

css

```
.grid__item {
  margin: 0 10px 20px;
  flex: 1 1 290px;
}

.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 2px;
  line-height: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card__body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 215px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #eee;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.card__body img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.card__footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.media__obj {
  width: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
  margin-right: 15px;
  background-size: contain;
}

.media__body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.media__body a {
  font-family: Courier, serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.media__body a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Reason why the user image is larger than you want it to be is because of the styles applied on `.cad__body img` selector. Width and height of the image in this selector is overriding the width and height in `.media__obj` selector. If you change `.media__obj` to `img.media__obj`, you will get the desired result. [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-grass-z6xvl?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: wow that works. also how do i bring the load more button to middle? `margin: 0 auto` not working

Comment: Setting margin left and right of the button to `auto` won't work because the container element of load more button is only as wide as the button. Add `margin: 0 auto;` on `.pagination__right` instead of on the button.